# Add ref to SYSTEM.WEB.EXTENSIONS‬

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-config, system.web

I have the follow lines:

`[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        private global::AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager @__BuildControlToolkitScriptManager1() {
            global::AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager @__ctrl;`

and I got this error:

```
The type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

I choose `Add Reference>.Net>system.web.extension version 4.0` in visual web developer and still get same error .

What can I do?

Comment: What version of the AjaxControlToolkit are you using?

Comment: Maybe `Version=3.5.0.0`?

Comment: @JaredShaver  i use AJAXControlToolkit Version 40412

Comment: That version is almost two years old, you may want to upgrade to the latest version.  That error sounds like you might be using the 3.5 version of AjaxControlToolkit instead of the 4.0 one inside a 4.0 project or you had a 3.5 project that you upgraded to 4.0 but the 3.5 assembly information got left in the web.config.